# How many squad points do you need you unlock everything in COD: Ghosts?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

There are a lot of equipment/perks/slots you can unlock with squad points in COD: Ghosts.  Some of the perks will automatically unlock by ranking up normally without spending any squad points.

At what point you can actually unlock everything and how many squad points and/or ranks would you need?

Comment: From [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/703504-call-of-duty-ghosts/cheats).  Note: I am assuming you are playing on Xbox360?

Comment: @Brian: I'm not sure your link points to where it should be.